# What does this icon mean in blender outliner?

Tags: outliner

[image: Outliner icon that I cant find meaning for, 3 lines almost in xyz orientation]

I imported a file from a different program, and am wondering what this icon means. I don't think its a collection or anything cause when I hit off, it just removes the dotted lines between the mass amount of objects I imported. Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an empty object, and dot lines indicate parent-child relationships between objects.

If this empty object is the parent of other objects, those objects will inherit the transformations of this empty object.

Usually, empty object is retained to facilitate the overall movement of other objects.

[image]